# C# RSACryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt has an equivalent to PHP function

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, encryption, rsa

I have assigned to convert some C# code to PHP. I really don't have knowledge in C# or on any Microsoft Programming languages. I need to connect to a web service with **RSA** encryption, they gave the public key and a sample code made in C# (that I need to convert). Below is the C# code:

```
//SAMPLE data to encrypt
var data = "dfsdfpamf12031ad";

var flStr = "<BitStrength>1024</BitStrength><RSAKeyValue><Modulus>** some keys **</Modulus><Exponent>**exponent value **</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>";

var bitStr = flStr.Substring(0, flStr.IndexOf("</BitStrength>", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) + 14); 

flStr = flStr.Replace(bitStr, "");
var bitStrength = Convert.ToInt32(bitStr.Replace("<BitStrength>", "").Replace("</BitStrength>", ""));
using (var rsaCrypto = new rsaCrypto(bitStrength))
{
    rsaCrypto.FromXmlString(flStr);
    var keySize = bitStrength / 8;
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(data);
    var maxLength = keySize - 42;
    var dataLength = bytes.Length;
    var iterations = dataLength / maxLength;
    var returnStr = new returnStr();
    for (var i = 0; i <= iterations; i++)
    {
        var tempBytes = new byte[(dataLength - maxLength * i > maxLength) ? maxLength : dataLength - maxLength * i]; // **i=0 ~ 86; i=1 ~ 42;** 
        Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, maxLength * i, tempBytes, 0, tempBytes.Length);
        var encryptedBytes = rsaCrypto.Encrypt(tempBytes, true);
        returnStr.Append(Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes));
    }
    return returnStr.ToString();
}
```

I don't think if there is a RSA byte encryption in PHP. I believe PHP don't have a byte data type. I tried to use `openssl_public_encrypt` function and `phpseclib` library but I think `86` and `42` when encrypted it considers it an integer data type not byte.

I'll appreciate any inputs regarding on this problem. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Can you get that C# code replaced by good crypto? Splitting a message into blocks which you then encrypt independently with RSA isn't a good idea. The rest of the code is pretty WTF as well.

Comment: We really hope we could do that but this is a existing client code. We need to support based on their existing API. They encrypt and decrypt it this way so we need to follow their methodology. As for our task we need to encrypt it using PHP. I hope there's still way to do accomplish this. :) Thanks for replying.